# .Net Where to find the official specification of the BinaryFormatter serialization format?

Tags: .net, binaryformatter

I'd like to know what is the serialization format of the BinaryFormatter. I found [this site](http://primates.ximian.com/~lluis/dist/binary_serialization_format.htm) which give some good informations, but it was obtained by reverse engineering and it is not complete.

Where can I find the official specification of the BinaryFormatter serialization format?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're looking for.  Do you mean something more official than MSDN?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[[MS-NRBF]: .NET Remoting: Binary Format Data Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236844(PROT.10).aspx)