# How to serialize properties with slashes in the name using BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter

###### Problem

I need to figure out the structure of a class that I do not have access to that was serialized using `BinaryFormatter`, so that I can serialize more files in the same structure.

###### What I have tried

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71970836/17263281) as reference I was able to make the following code:

```cs
private static T TransformMSNRBFToObject<T>(byte[] data) where T : new()
{
   var response = new T();
   using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))            
   Write((BinaryObject)NRBFReader.ReadStream(stream));            
   return response
 }

private static void Write(BinaryObject bObj, string name = "", int depth = 0)
{
   Trace.WriteLine($"{name} [{bObj.TypeName}] [{bObj.AssemblyName}]");
                        
   foreach (var key in bObj.Keys)
   {
       bObj.TryGetValue(key, out var value);

       if (value is BinaryObject obj)
          Write(obj, key, depth + 1);
       else
        Trace.WriteLine($"{value?.GetType().FullName} {key}");
    }
 }
```

This was able to determine the structures of multiple classes, including their namespaces & assemblies. This has got me most of the way there, but there are a few items left that I am unsure how to handle.

###### Properties

There are what appear to be properties that all have a forward slash `/` within the variable name. They are all of `primitive` types.

E.g. `Item0/B`, `Item1/B`, `Setting/1/Index`, `Setting/2/Value`, etc.

###### Methods

There is also something that I am unable to identify, but my best guess is that they are methods since the name always contains the word `Method`.

When I output the key I get: `DoSomethingMethod`

When I output the namespace I get: `NamespaceName+DoSomethingMethods`

They always contain a key that gives this: `System.Int32 value__`

I am assuming that `value__` is either an input parameter, or the return type.

However, when I add a method it does not serialize.

###### Questions

- Where is the variable supposed to be stored to result in a `/` within the variable name?
- Alternatively, is there a way like with `XmlSerializer`'s `[XmlAttribute("attributeName")]` that I could decorate a property to force it to have a specific name?
- What is the format of the items that appear to be methods?

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` is intentionally a closed opaque box; and it is an obsolete and deprecated box; honestly, I think any answer that ends with you propagating `BinaryFormatter` code: is a bad outcome that is going to just keep hurting you